# Prove that $(\sum x^2)^3\ge9\sum x^4yz$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

> Prove that $\displaystyle\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^3\ge9\left(x^4yz+y^4xz+z^4xy\right)$, for $x$, $y$, $z\in\Bbb R_+$.

The $pqr$ method doesn't seem possible because the power is too high.
$$\iff\left(p^2-2q\right)^2\ge9r\left(p^3-3pq+3r\right).$$

Then expand the expression to get
$$\sum x^6+3\sum\left(x^4y^2+x^2y^4\right)+6x^2y^2z^2\ge9\sum x^4yz.$$
I wanted to use SOS but cannot find the weight of three squares, my progress:
$$3\sum x^4(y-z)^2=3\sum\left(x^4y^2+x^2y^4\right)-6\sum x^4yz.$$
Whats left is $\displaystyle\sum x^6+6x^2y^2z^2-3\sum x^4yz$. I have trouble dealing with it.

Comment: I'm curious about the way of proving that stronger inequality you obtained by SOS , $\sum x^6+6x^2y^2z^2\geqslant3\sum x^4yz$ . I tried to divide both sides by $(xyz)^2$ and let $a=(x^2)/(yz),~\ldots$ , which yields $\sum a^2+6\geqslant3\sum a$ for $abc=1$ . That's the furthest I can go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: A simpler pqr

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(p^2-2q\right)^3\ge9r\left(p^3-3pq+3r\right).$$

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$ and $pq \ge 9r$, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(p^2-2q\right)^3\ge 9 \cdot \frac{q^2}{3p}\cdot\left(p^3-3pq+3 \cdot \frac{pq}{9}\right)$$
or
$$(p^2 - 2q)^3 \ge q^2(3p^2 - 8q)$$
or
$$(p^2 - 2q)^3 + (2q)^3 \ge 3p^2 q^2$$
or (using $x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)[(x + y)^2 - 3xy]$)
$$p^2[p^4 - 3(p^2 - 2q)\cdot 2q] \ge 3p^2 q^2$$
or
$$p^2 (p^2 - 3q)^2 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Good. But what's the idea for transforming the inequality about $p$, $q$ and $r$? When I'm doing this, it's like trying my luck.

Comment: @youthdoo There are some most used relations among $p, q, r$. In experience, $q^2 \ge 3qr$, $p^2 \ge 3q$ and degree 3/4 Schur's inequalities etc. are often used. If all of them fail, you may used the ultimate $$0 \le (a - b)^2(b - c)^2(c - a)^2 = - 4p^3r + p^2q^2 + 18pqr - 4q^3 - 27r^2$$ which is quadratic in $r$ (gives you $\cdots \le r \le \cdots$).

Comment: Thanks, so is it that\\[0 \le (a - b)^2(b - c)^2(c - a)^2 = - 4p^3r + p^2q^2 + 18pqr - 4q^3 - 27r^2.\\]is the necessary sufficient condition right?

Comment: @youthdoo Yes, $a, b, c\ge 0$ is equivalent to $p, q, r \ge 0$ and $- 4p^3r + p^2q^2 + 18pqr - 4q^3 - 27r^2\ge 0$ (the cubic $u^3 - pu^2 + qu -r = 0$ has three real non-negative roots).

Comment: @youthdoo You may see my answer [pqr](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459709/if-x-y-z0-prove-xyz-left-frac1x-frac1y-frac1z-right/3460737#3460737) for the book listing often used pqr relations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a proof that continues your SOS attempt, which is to prove

$$
\sum x^6+6x^2y^2z^2\geqslant3\sum x^4yz
$$

By noticing the following identity, this inequality is obviously true by Schur's inequality

$$
\sum(x^6+6x^2y^2z^2-3x^4yz)=\sum x^4(x-y)(x-z)+4(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2+2\sum yz(x-y)^2(x-z)^2+2xyz\sum x(x-y)(x-z)
$$

This proof is by brute force using the Triangle of Coefficient Method. Though I've found a way to simplify this inequality, I didn't managed to solve it that way.

Namely, by dividing both sides with $(xyz)^2$ , we obtain

$$
\sum\left(\frac{x^2}{yz}\right)^2+6\geqslant3\sum\frac{x^2}{yz}
$$

Let $a=(x^2)/(yz),~b=(y^2)/(zx),~c=(z^2)/(xy)$ , we have to prove that

$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+6\geqslant 3(a+b+c)
$$

for positive real numbers $a,b,c$ such that $abc=1$ .

I hope someone would continue my attempt.

**Edit.** This edition contains a new proof of this inequality using SOS Method by [LasterCircle](https://www.zhihu.com/people/gao-jing-xiang-42)

$$
\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}=\frac12\sum\left[\sum x^4+2xy(x^2+xy+y^2)-2xyz\sum x\right](x-y)^2
$$

It's apparent that $\sum x^4+2xy(x^2+xy+y^2)-2xyz\sum x>0$ , the inequality is true.

**Edit2.** River Li has given a nice proof in the comment.

And here's a simpler SOS

$$
\sum(x^6-3x^4yz)+6x^2y^2z^2=\frac1{18}\sum\left(x(x^2-yz)\right)^2+\frac12\sum x^2(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)+\frac12\sum{x^2y^2(x-y)^2}\geqslant0
$$

Comment: Do you mean [Chinese Dumbass Notation](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/SOS_Dumbass/SOS_Dumbass.pdf)?

Comment: @youthdoo Right, that's its another name (probably more widely known)  , I have made some progress on this inequality and I'll show it in the next edition.

Comment: But isn't the last inequality obvious. Because $a^2-a\ge-\dfrac14$?

Comment: @youthdoo Please note that $\sum a^2\ne\left(\sum a\right)^2$ .

Comment: @O-17 Some typos? $a^2+b^2+c^2+6\ge 3(a+b+c)$?

Comment: @O-17 By the way, a proof for the above: WLOG, assume that $(b-1)(c-1)\ge 0$, we have$a^2+b^2+c^2+6-3(a+b+c) + (abc-1) $ $$= \frac12(a + b + c- 3)^2 
 + \frac12(a - 1)^2 + a(b - 1)(c - 1) + \frac12 (b-c)^2 \ge 0.$$

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for correcting, and your proof is very nice too.

Comment: Your method is called Schur splitting, which seldom works. But it miraculously solved this inequality...

Comment: @youthdoo I don't know if my method is Schur splitting, but I definitely wouldn't call this method 'seldom works'. I acknowledged from your homepage that you're also from China, welcome to 'the seminar of Triangle of Coefficient' (q gruop: 875413273)

Comment: @youthdoo By the way, your inequality may be refined to $\sum a^6+(24-9\sqrt{3})\sum a^2b^2c^2\geqslant(9-3\sqrt{3})\sum a^4bc$ by a theorem that is introduced in a book in that q group. It may be proved by its equivalence to $\sum\left((a^2+\sqrt{3}bc)\sum\left((a+b-\sqrt{3}c)(a-b)^2\right)\right)\geqslant0$ , which is obviously true.

Comment: The problem is, we need every single coefficient non-negative to conclude a polynomial $\ge0$, and very often one of them $<0$, and we need to do further work.

Comment: Which question? Proving $\sum x^6+6x^2y^2z^2\ge3\sum x^4yz$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the expression is symmetric, WLOG, $ z \geq y \geq x$.
Let $ x = a, y = a + b, z = a+b+c$, where $a, b, c \geq 0$.

Then, expanding out $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3 - 9 xyz(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ gives us, courtesy of [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a%5E2%2B%28a%2Bb%29%5E2%2B%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E2%29%5E3+-+9%28a%29%28a%2Bb%29%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%28a%5E3%2B%28a%2Bb%29%5E3%2B%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E3%29):

$9 a^4 b^2 + 9 a^4 b c + 9 a^4 c^2 + 28 a^3 b^3 + 42 a^3 b^2 c + 30 a^3 b c^2 + 8 a^3 c^3 + 42 a^2 b^4 + 84 a^2 b^3 c + 78 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 36 a^2 b c^3 + 12 a^2 c^4 + 30 a b^5 + 75 a b^4 c + 90 a b^3 c^2 + 60 a b^2 c^3 + 27 a b c^4 + 6 a c^5 + 8 b^6 + 24 b^5 c + 36 b^4 c^2 + 32 b^3 c^3 + 18 b^2 c^4 + 6 b c^5 + c^6.$

Since all the coefficients are non-negative, this is clearly non-zero, hence we are done.

Comment: Is this method called the Buffalos Way?

Comment: @youthdoo Yes. Often, the more common way BW appears is to set $ x = \min{x, y, z}, y = x+u, z = x+v$, and still requiring a bunch of SOS to resolve.  In this case, this approach immediately yields non-negative coefficients, so we are done.

Comment: A bit irrelevant but how do you copy the result from wolfram alpha to paste here? Use ocr?

Comment: Hover on the relevant line, click on the "Plain text" tab, then click the "Copyable Plain text" which will copy it to clipboard, then paste it.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is true for any real variables.

Indeed, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ may be negative and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(9u^2-6v^2)^3\geq9w^3(27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3)$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ is a concave function.

But, a concave function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$, which by [uvw](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791) happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is symmetric,  even degree and homogeneous, it's enough to assume that $y=z=1$ (for $y=z=0$ the equality is obvious), which gives $$(x^2+2)^3-9x(x^3+2)\geq0$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(x^4+2x^3-2x+8)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$x^4+2x^3-2x+8=(x^2+x-1)^2+x^2+7>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

By AM-GM we obtain: $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3-9xyz(x^3+y^3+z^3)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x^6+3x^4y^2+3x^4z^2+2x^2y^2z^2-9x^4yz)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(2x^6-x^4y^2-x^4z^2+7x^4y^2+7x^4z^2-14x^4yz-4x^4yz+4x^2y^2z^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2((x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2+7z^4-2xyz(x+y+z))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2((z^2-xy)^2+6z^4-2xy(x+y)z+(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2-x^2y^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(6z^4-\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^3z+\frac{7}{16}(x+y)^4\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(6z^4+3\cdot\frac{7}{48}(x+y)^4-\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^3z\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(4\sqrt[4]{6z^4\left(\frac{7}{48}(x+y)^4\right)^3}-\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^3z\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x+y)^3z\left(4\sqrt[4]{6\left(\frac{7}{48}\right)^3}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Due to homogeneization we have :

$$\left(x^{2}+1^{2}+c^{2}\right)^{3}-9xc\left(x^{3}+1^{3}+c^{3}\right)$$

We need to show for $x\ge 1$ and WLOG $c\geq 1$

$$f(x)=\left(x^{2}+1^{2}+c^{2}\right)^{3}-9xc\left(x^{3}+1^{3}+c^{3}\right)\geq 0$$

The function is convex on $(0,\infty)$ because we have :

$$f''(x)=6(c^{6}+6c^{3}x^{2}+2c^{3}-18cx^{2}+5x^{4}+6x^{2}+1)>0$$

So we use the tangent line method we have :

$$f(x)\geq f(1)(x-1)+f(1)=(6 (c^3 + 2)^2 - 9 c (c^3 + 2) - 27 c)(x-1)+(c^3 + 2)^3 - 9 c (c^3 + 2)\geq 0$$

Because :

$$(6(c^{3}+2)^{2}-9c(c^{3}+2)-27c)\geq 0,(c^3 + 2)^3 - 9 c (c^3 + 2)=(c^3 + 2) (c - 1) (c^5 + c^4 + c^3 + 5 c^2 + 5 c - 4)\geq 0$$